# Have GtkVolumeButton popup 'overflow' over window border

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gtkvolumebutton

I was wondering if there was a way to have the popup from a GtkVolumeButton flow over the edge of the GtkWindow edge. Currently, I'm running into this problem:
[image]

**EDIT**: This is what I'm looking for (if it's possible):
[image]

I would like the volume selection popup to not be bounded by the window's edges. I'm not sure how the internals of gtk+ widget/window drawing work, so I'm not even sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GtkHeaderBar to replace the system decorations with client side decorations. You can even put the control buttons and everything else in the GtkHeaderBar, so this application can take up even less space.

Comment: I was hoping for something that would help me achieve my goal without re-architecting with a GtkHeaderBar. I will update my question with and example of what I'm looking for (a touched up image).